Snowflake - Querying JSON
I need some help in getting this JSON file ingested in Snowflake so I can make queries on it:
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
  "etag": "kBCr3I9kLHHU79W4Ip5196LDptI",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
      "etag": "IfWa37JGcqZs-jZeAyFGkbeh6bc",
      "id": "1",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Film & Animation",
        "assignable": true,
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
      "etag": "5XGylIs7zkjHh5940dsT5862m1Y",
      "id": "2",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
        "assignable": true,
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
      "etag": "HCjFMARbBeWjpm6PDfReCOMOZGA",
      "id": "10",
      "snippet": {
        "title": "Music",
        "assignable": true,
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
      }

Note the json data is stored as an external table in snowflake called e_table_youtube_category
I tried using the query:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_youtube_category as
SELECT
items.VALUE:"snippet"."title"::string as title,
items.VALUE:"id"::int as id,
FROM e_table_youtube_category,
LATERAL FLATTEN(items);

Error reads: Error: invalid identifier 'ITEMS.VALUE'
Any ideas?

This should show you how to achieve what you want:
with jdata as (
SELECT try_PARSE_JSON(column1) AS mycolumn
FROM VALUES
('{
    "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
    "etag": "kBCr3I9kLHHU79W4Ip5196LDptI",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
            "etag": "IfWa37JGcqZs-jZeAyFGkbeh6bc",
            "id": "1",
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Film & Animation",
                "assignable": true,
                "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
            "etag": "5XGylIs7zkjHh5940dsT5862m1Y",
            "id": "2",
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
                "assignable": true,
                "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
            }
        },
        {
            "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
            "etag": "HCjFMARbBeWjpm6PDfReCOMOZGA",
            "id": "10",
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Music",
                "assignable": true,
                "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
)
)
select j.mycolumn, i.value:id::string, i.value:snippet:title::string
from jdata j, LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => mycolumn:items) i;

;

